# Many to Many Match in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating an website with javascript where users can find other users with similar interests. I would like to have one user have interests for example:

```
dogs
cats
books
```

and in the database I will have many users with interests like so:

```
USER 1    USER 2    USER 3
apples    school    apple
cats      books     dogs
pears     cats      lions
```

Then what I would like is to be able to find the user that has the most similar interests. For example in this case user 2 should be returned because it has two matching interest whereas the rest only have one similar. And my interest list will be anywhere between 10 and 200 interests so it can't loop through them all or that would take fore ever. Please let me know if anyone has a solution. This has been very difficult for me.

Let me know if you need any more explanations.
Thanks

**UPDATE**
This is what my database currently looks like.

```
user
  interests
    apple: true
    pear: true
    book: true
    school: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out for anyone interested, I reformatted my database to have a category interests. Then I listed each person who had that interest under them in the category.

Answer (score 0):

Take a good look at the example how to create scalable data over at the Firebase Docs: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#fanout Hint: the "groups" are your "interests".

Comment: I figured out how to do it in the database, my problem is accessing it. How can I access data by matching multiple items to multiple in someone else's list.

Comment: Depends, how does your database structure look like now?

Comment: I have it structured where it has user then a child interest with many interests. I have updated my original post to show the structure